# How to create modern segmented control?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I was wondering how to create a segmented control with just the bottom border like this:

[image]

I searched everywhere but I can't find an updated answer because they have just updated how segmented controls look. If anyone could provide the code or get me on the right track it would be very helpful.

Comment: you can create custom component using stack view

Comment: You've *"searched everywhere"*? Try searching for `custom segmented control swift`. Many, many examples / tutorials / libraries / etc. If you can't find one that looks *exactly* how you want, then start with one that looks close and modify it.

Comment: @DonMag I have looked that up although nothing is close to what I want for example: transparent background, bottom border etc

Comment: @appledeveloper123 - does this look close? https://medium.com/code-with-coffee/create-a-custom-segmented-control-6488400f8705

Comment: @DonMag I already tried that but got a bunch of errors

Comment: @appledeveloper123 - well, if it looks like what you're going for, it could be a good starting point. Even if you get errors, or maybe **particularly** if you get errors, could be.a great learning experience!

Comment: @appledeveloper123 - I just grabbed that example from the linked GitHub repo. Fixed 3 (apparent) typos. Works like a charm.

Comment: @DonMag what code did you copy?

Comment: @DonMag I just copied that but I am having trouble fixing one of the errors, would we be able to enter a chat

Comment: @appledeveloper123 - download the example from GitHub (link is at the bottom of that article). Open the project and try to build it. Three errors. Two where "seletedIndex" should be "sele**c**tedIndex" and one where "_seletedIndex" should be "sele**c**tedIndex" (without the leading underscore).

Comment: @DonMag yes but I'm confused what I should add in the storyboard

Comment: @appledeveloper123 - I don't want this to sound bad, but you need to do some work. Once you made those "selectedIndex" corrections so the example app runs, spend ***at least several hours*** going through that code. ***Learn*** what it's doing, so you can use it and/or make any changes to get it to where you want it. This is very, very basic.

Answer (score 0):

I use this link one time   [Custom segment Button With CGRect](https://medium.com/code-with-coffee/create-a-custom-segmented-control-6488400f8705)

you should try to draw the segment button on a path and you can give any specification you want.